# django admin how to display widget on readonly field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-widget

I want to display my widget on the field at django admin when the field is readonly.

**admin.py**

```
class AudioTrackAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AudioTrack
    form = AudioTrackForm
    readonly_fields = ('file',)
```

**forms.py**

```
class AudioTrackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = AudioTrack
        widgets = { 'file': MediaFileInput, } # my widget
```

When the file is not readonly, it displays widget OK. But when i include it as readonly, i see text line. (Django does not to use my form if readonly)

How can i get it to use form even at readonly field?

**or**

How to display another widget if i set my field readonly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say it's a feature.

When field is set to readonly, Django uses [`display_for_field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/98cfb90182a8baa806fc4e09e294b6cfc5d09eff/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L418) function which hardcodes the result, you can't customize it.

Another approach would be not to set the field as readonly and override [`formfield_for_dbfield`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L87), an undocumented `ModelAdmin` method and act accordingly to your needs.

Comment: Overriding `formfield_for_dbfield` is dangerous since users can submit a `POST` and tamper fields you intended to be readonly (or just use the inspector to enable it).

Answer (score 8):

An alternative and more flexible solution is to set the "disabled" attribute of those fields you want to render in read-only mode, overriding the `get_form(...)` method of your admin class:

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):

    form = super(SupplierAdmin, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)

    for field_name in self.fake_readonly_fields:
        form.base_fields[field_name].disabled = True

    return form
```

note that I take the name of readonly fields not from the usual `self.readonly_fields` but from a different array that I named `self.fake_readonly_fields`, in order to avoid name overlaps

The limit of the proposed solution (using `formfield_for_dbfield`) is that in that way you render at the same way all the database fields of a given type, wether it should be read-only or not. That way works if your entire form should be read-only, but if you deals with forms that are half read-only and half not, it is better to rely on the `disabled` attribute.

Further details on my answer here: [django modeladmin, readonly_fields and boolean fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701035/django-modeladmin-readonly-fields-and-boolean-fields/22701663#22701663)

Comment: This should use the `disabled` `Field` attribute, since not all widgets support the (HTML) attribute (e.g. with a `django.contrib.gis.forms.fields.PointField`), and it could be changed by the user!  So `form.base_fields[field_name].disabled = True` should be used.

Comment: In case of related fields (e.g. `ForeignKey` fields), you may want to remove the little buttons that add / edit / delete related objects. This can be done by setting the appropriate formfield widget attributes, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54775596/).