# How can I remove the add and change buttons from a TabularInline admin field?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models `A`, `B`, and `AB`.
`A` objects have a `ManyToManyField` called `A.m` that can link to many `B` objects, through my intermediary model `AB`.
I have a very nice `TabularInline` section full of `AB` objects, on my admin page for my `A` model.

All is well.  Except that the `TabularInline` section shows "Add" and "Change" buttons for the `B` object in each `AB` object's row, and I want to remove those buttons.  I still want to be able to add, change, and delete `AB` objects rows, just not the `B` objects they reference.

I have tried setting the `can_add_related`, `can_change_related`, `can_delete_related` attributes to `False`, but this does nothing.

```
class ABInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AB
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super(ABInline, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.base_fields['m'].widget.can_add_related = False
        form.base_fields['m'].widget.can_change_related = False
        form.base_fields['m'].widget.can_delete_related = False
        return form
```

Is this a bug?  Or is there a different way to accomplish this for `TabularInline` fields?

Comment: The `get_form` method is not implemented on `TabularInline` ([only](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L659) on `ModelAdmin`). That's why nothing happens. Otherwise I think it would not work either, because you need to change the widget for the field on `AB` that points to `B`, whereas `'m'` is a field on `A`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP's idea of setting the widget's attributes should work.

The basic idea is as follows:

The actual form field in the `TabularInline` for `AB` that allows you to select the `B` object is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield). This field has a [Select](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#select) widget, wrapped in a [RelatedFieldWidgetWrapper](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L234). The latter controls the "add" and "change" (or "edit") buttons next to the select box. To remove these buttons, set the widget's `can_add_related` and `can_change_related` attributes to `False`.

This is actually what the OP attempted to do. However, the OP tried to extend `get_form`, but that method is only available on a `ModelAdmin`, not on the `TabularInline`, as far as I know ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L659)).

Instead of using `get_form`, we can extend e.g. `formfield_for_dbfield` ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.7/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L132)) on the `TabularInline`, as illustrated below (based on OP's example):

```
class ABInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AB

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        formfield = super(ABInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
        if db_field.name == 'b':
            # Assuming AB.b is the ForeignKey to B
            formfield.widget.can_add_related = False
            formfield.widget.can_change_related = False
            # formfield.widget.can_delete_related = False  # default is already False
        return formfield
```

Here we assume that the OP's `AB` model looks something like this:

```
class AB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(to='A', ...)
    b = models.ForeignKey(to='B', ...)
    ...
```

Comment: Note that this works in `formfield_for_dbfield()` (or in `get_form()` with minor modification), but it does *not* work e.g. in `formfield_for_foreignkey()`, because `formfield_for_dbfield()` will then reset the permissions based on those of the related model admin. See [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L166).

Answer (score 3):

You could try with this functions:

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options)

```
class ABInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = AB

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
      return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
      return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
      return False
```

Comment: This does not answer the question: OP says "I still want to be able to add, edit and remove AB objects rows, just not the B objects they reference." This answer affects the AB objects, not the B objects. That's the other way round.

Comment: If  `has_change_permission` returns `False`, the "add" and "change" buttons do indeed disappear, but only for existing items. They are still available for new (`extra`) inline items. Moreover, the select box for the existing items will become "read only".