Resize readonly fields in Django Admi
In my Django admin im currently displaying JSONField as readonly, the JSON data is quite large and takes up about 80-90% of the page. I was able to find an answer for how one might resize a not readonly field here but other then that I am lost. My ideal outcome would have the large JSON data in a scrollable text box like so: Ideal outcome
How can I control the size of a readonly field without truncating the data?

This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832739/django-admin-how-to-display-widget-on-readonly-field

The easiest way is to create a “custom-field” method in ModelAdmin instead of a readonly field in the form and display it as a scrollable div:
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    
    fields = ...., my_custom_field_mehod, ...
    readonly_fields = ...., my_custom_field_mehod, ...
    
    def my_custom_field_mehod(self, object=None):
        if obj:
            return mark_safe(f'<div class="scrollable">{obj.my_json_data}</div>')
        return ''

More info about “custom-field” here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields
